# How to know if its the props that changed or the inner state in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with inner state that I want to update its initial state using props so I have to watch the props too. however I'd like to know when its the props that changed so that I run the function related to it once and keep it away from the inner component state.\

This is because I am unable to properly update the inner state as that thing will always run everytime the useEffect triggers

the following useEffect is for a Modal that I am setting visible or not from the parent component state(so its always mounted).

```
useEffect(() => {
    // I want to run the following once
    if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(propState).length !== 0) {
      console.log(propState);
      setState(()=> {
       innerState = propState.user_name
      });
      
    }
  }, [propState, innerState]);
```

Comment: Run once when the component mounts? Or only once after some condition is met? Can you provide us more context with a more complete code example and more clearly explain the use case? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added some lines to explain why mounted might not be possible. the condition would be to compare old props with new props which I am not quite sure how to do either @DrewReese let me know if its enough

Comment: I see. If you are looking for something more synonymous to `componentDidUpdate` where you can compare current values with values from the previous render then I suggest following this React Hooks FAQ topic [How to get the previous props or state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state). It details how to create a `usePrevious` hook to cache a value from the previous render cycle fo use as a comparison.

Comment: Consider using the useRef hook to hold previous values and do a check on that. This is a decent, light article on how you could achieve what you want. https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-get-previous-props-state-with-react-hooks/

Comment: You can add any number off useEffects In your component, add 2 useEffects one for propState and one for innerState

Answer (score 0):

You can check value in inner state and propState. If they equal, when skip setState.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (propState?.user_name && propState !== innerState.user_name) {
      setState(()=> {
       innerState = propState.user_name
      });
      
    }
  }, [propState, innerState]);
```